# Why does ServletContext#getRealPath("/") return a relative path?

Tags: java, servlets, jakarta-ee

I have the following snippet of code:

```
String path = servletContext.getRealPath("/");
```

Now I got a bugreport from a user saying that the returned path is not an absolute path.
The returned path is '`usr/local/...`' instead of '`/usr/local/...'` , so `getRealPath` seems to be returning a relative path.

I can see this, because the returned path is logged into a logfile.

My specs are:

- JBoss 4.0.5.GA
- Redhat EL 4
- jdk 1.5.0

See [here](http://java.sun.com/j2ee/sdk_1.3/techdocs/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#getRealPath%28java.lang.String%29) for the javadoc

Comment: Are you sure that your logging is not just dropping the first char for some reason? Can you maybe debug into the app and check the result that way? If all that fails, you might check for bug reports on this issue at Sun.

Comment: No unfortunately not.
 1: it's a simple log statement: log.debug("path: " + path);
 2: Later on in the application some code tries to lookup a file under that path: new File(servletContext.getRealPath("/) + ...);
a call on file.exists() returns false.

Good idea though, i'll check the bug reports.

Comment: You mention you are using JBoss, but which web container? It used to come with Jetty by default, but now Tomcat I think... you might also check into this issue on the bug database and/or forums for the web container you are actually using since it's their implementation... didnt think of that earlier.

Answer (score 1):

Something like

```
String path = new File(servletContext.getRealPath("/")).getAbsolutePath();
```

should solve your problem. (It does not answer your Question though...;-) )

Regards, Jan

Comment: I don't think so :)

Say servletContext.getRealPath("/") returns 'usr/local/...'

new File("usr/local/...") will ONLY work when the current working directory is / (root).

Comment: Did you try it? It will return an absolute file (It does on my mac with jetty running as a servlet container) ;-)

Comment: That goes back to my comment on the question... I wonder if its an implementation issue since you just tested in Jetty and JBoss uses Tomcat I believe. The docs and spec say it should work, but they have to implement it correctly :-)

Comment: As far as I remember Jboss uses tomcat by default as it's webcontainer. You can configure it to use Jetty to. 
Or just try it with "new File("/").getAbsoluteFilePath() as a fallback. ;-)